# AngularJS can't find nested template files

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with AngularJS and am having a simple but odd issue. AngularJS is unable to locate my template file if it is in a subdirectory of a specific directory.

The below project structure is what I wish to have. I reference `myFile.html` by using the templateUrl property on a component `templateUrl: "/MyApp/posts/myFile/myFile.html"` With below structure and this import, AngularJS throws an error.

```
public
  | javascript
  | MyApp
    | posts
        | app.js
        | index.html
        | myFile
            myFile.html
```

If I reformat my structure to the below, and change my import to `templateUrl: "/MyApp/myFile/myFile.html"` everything works

```
public
  | javascript
  | MyApp
    | posts
        | app.js
        | index.html
    | myFile
       | myFile.html
```

Please don't suggest that I check the spelling, and file path. I've done that a million times and it just never works if it's in a sub directory of the posts directory

Comment: Are you running a dev server?
If so, can you access the template by fetching/browsing `http://localhost/MyApp/myFile/myFile.html` ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. Turns out it was an issue with how Babel was transpiling the project. Another member of our team was able to sort it out :)